# Add CSS class during Angular form validation

Tags: angular

I want to add a custom class name when validating the form

I now use ngClass` to achieve, but this is very troublesome, is there a simpler way to achieve

```html
<input formControlName="username"
  [ngClass]="{
    'my-invalid': username.invalid,
    'my-valid': username.valid
  }"
/>
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"very troublesome"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier now

```
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControlStatus } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBsFormControl]',
})
export class BsFormControlDirective {
  constructor(private ngControlStatus: NgControlStatus) {}

  @HostBinding('class.is-valid')
  get valid() {
    return this.ngControlStatus.ngClassValid;
  }

  @HostBinding('class.is-invalid')
  get invalid() {
    return this.ngControlStatus.ngClassInvalid;
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" formControlName="username" appBsFormControl />
```

Comment: I saw better code [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1143/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms#how-are-css-classes-added-depending-on-abstractcontrol-s-status)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to `[class.]`

```html
<input formControlName="username" 
  [class.my-invalid]='username.invalid'
  [class.my-valid]='username.valid'
/>
```

Its simpler and easy to make changes

Comment: Can you please explain how this is simpler and easier to make changes?

Comment: This is really good, but is there any other simpler way XDD

Comment: Use a directive or angular configuration

Comment: @ThomasSablik this approach avoids creating Objects on the html as noted while using `[ngClass]`

Comment: Yes, you changed the syntax. You're using two directives instead of one. But please compare OP's code and your code. There is nearly no difference. How does this increase the usability? How does it make anything simpler or easier to change? Can you provide an example for code that gets simpler with this change? You provided a different code to achieve the same result but IMHO it's in no way simpler or easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can set custom CSS classes for your form controls in easy way. You create a directive, and in there, you simply bind your own CSS classes to the statuses that `NgControl` defines for your inputs (form controls). Finally use your directive on any of your form controls. [Click here](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/tip-of-the-week-6-409be82ffe08) to learn more.

`app.module.ts` file:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControlDirective} from './shared/form-control.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    FormControlDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule,
  ],
  ...
})
```

`form-control.directive.ts` file:

```
import { Self, Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl  } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFormControl]',
})
export class FormControlDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.is-valid') get isValid(): boolean {
    return this.ctrlDir.touched && this.ctrlDir.valid;
  }

  @HostBinding('class.is-invalid') get isInvalid(): boolean {
    return this.ctrlDir.touched && this.ctrlDir.invalid;
  }

  constructor(@Self() private ctrlDir: NgControl) {}
}
```

`app.component.html` file:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" #form="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="femail">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="femail" ngModel name="email" required email appFormControl>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```